# Cree un controlador en php con laragon, pero cuando declaro su ruta me marca el siguiente error

Tags: php, laragon

syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería bueno que nos muestres en la imagen la ubicación del controlador así descartamos problemas en la ruta o la escritura... Así también sería bueno nos muestre el use que haces para usarlo

Comment: También estaría bien ver el código que justamente queda tapado con ese error, pues quizás el error está allí escondido. No uses imágenes para pegar el código, pégalo como texto pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] para modificar la pregunta.

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible.

Comment: Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].